# InfluxDB write failure node-influx library

Tags: node.js, docker, time-series, influxdb

I am writing data to influxdb using the node-influx library.

https://github.com/node-influx/node-influx

It writes about 500,000 records and then I start seeing this error following which there are no more writes. It looks like a dns issue but I am running it inside a docker container on `ubuntu 18.04` host.

> Error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN influxdb influxdb:8086 |at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)

I have the logging level set to `debug` but I am not seeing any other errors. Any idea what might be causing this?

**Update**

1. tried with a different influx version
2. increased ulimit of host
3. used ip address of docker-container instead of service name, no error is thrown, writes stop after sometime silently
4. tried to call the write API with `curl`

```
curl -i -XPOST 'http://localhost:8086/write?db=mydb' --data-binary 'snmp,hostipv4=172.16.102.82,oidname=cpu_idle,site=gotham value=1000 1574751020815819489'
```

This works and a record is inserted in the DB.

**Update2**
It seems to be a dns issue on the docker network. I am not able to ping the influxdb container from the worker container. The writes are not reaching influx.

**Update3**

As a workaround for now, I am forcing a `process.exit(1)` on catching the error on my worker and using `docker-compose restart: on-failure` to restart the service. This resumes the writes.

*retention policy is set for 2 days on the DB*

*influxdb.conf*

```
reporting-disabled = true 

[meta]
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/meta"
  retention-autocreate = false 
  logging-enabled = true

[logging]
  format = "auto"
  level = "debug"

[data]
  engine = "tsm1"
  dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/data"
  wal-dir = "/var/lib/influxdb/wal"
  wal-fsync-delay = "200ms"
  index-version = "inmem"
  wal-logging-enabled = true
  query-log-enabled = true
  cache-max-memory-size = "2g" 
  cache-snapshot-memory-size = "256m" 
  cache-snapshot-write-cold-duration = "20m"
  compact-full-write-cold-duration = "24h"
  max-concurrent-compactions = 0
  compact-throughput = "48m"
  max-points-per-block = 0
  max-series-per-database = 1000000
  trace-logging-enabled = false

[coordinator]
  write-timeout = "10s"
  max-concurrent-queries = 0
  query-timeout = "0s"
  log-queries-after = "0s"
  max-select-point = 0
  max-select-series = 0
  max-select-buckets = 0

[retention]
  enabled = true
  check-interval = "30m0s"

[shard-precreation]
  enabled = true
  check-interval = "10m0s"
  advance-period = "30m0s"

[monitor]
  store-enabled = true
  store-database = "_internal"
  store-interval = "10s"

[http]
  enabled = true
  bind-address = ":8086"
  auth-enabled = false
  log-enabled = true
  max-concurrent-write-limit = 0
  max-enqueued-write-limit = 0
  enqueued-write-timeout = 0

[continuous_queries]
  enabled = false 
  log-enabled = true
  run-interval = "10s"
```

Comment: Did you check influxdb log to validate whether requests are being reached to Influx or not? It seems the log you are looking at is client log.

Comment: you are correct they are not reaching influx. I have narrowed it down to a docker dns issue. I am not able to ping the influxdb container from the worker container after the error happens.

Comment: Ok, did you add proper networking settings for docker file?

Comment: I am using the default network in my docker-compose version 3. The writes happen till a point and then it stops. If I restart that service the writes start again.